# Stop and resume async calls

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, asynchronous, async-await

When navigating to page, i'm calling in the viewmodel

```
public void OnNavigatedTo()
    {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async o =>
        {
            collectionsAnswer = await productCategoriesDataService.RequestServerAsync();
            ***
            if (collectionsAnswer.status == Ok)
            {
                var parsedList = await productCategoriesDataService.Parse(collectionsAnswer.json);
                _itemsList = new List<ProductItem>(parsedList);
                DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
                    RaisePropertyChanged("ItemsList", _itemsList, _itemsList, true));
             }
        }
```

How to stop/resume it properly? I tried to Abort current HttpWebResponse (which is inside of RequestServerAsync() ) from OnNavigatedFrom(), but it crashed, when i'm returning to the same page again.

So, in short, the problem is:

1. Navigating to page starts await commands
2. Leaving the page (by pressing Back) should cancel current request
3. Visiting page should create new request, but awaits are still waiting (if to return fast enough)

Are there better ways to solve this problem? Maybe i should create new instances of viewmodels every time?

Comment: Do your productCategoriesDataService methods accept cancelation tokens?

Comment: And why are you submitting an asynchronous call to the ThreadPool? If RequestServerAsync is truly async, your call would end up in the ThreadPool anyway.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just to deal with freaking callbacks.

Comment: I don't see any callbacks in your code. Besides, with Tasks or async/await you no longer need callbacks. The only fishy call is DispatcherHelper which you could have avoided if you had NOT used ThreadPool. Async operations run on the ThreadPool but code between `await`s runs on the UI thread.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Of cource, there's no callbacks in my code, because i'm using async :) What i want - is to push all possible code to the background thread and do the minimal affect on UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancellations in the TPL and in async-await code are performed through the use of [`CancellationTokenSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Many asynchronous methods have an overload which accepts a `CancellationToken` as a parameter, this is then used by the method to observe for cancellation.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155759.aspx) is a post on the MSDN about how to initiate and handle the cancellation of async tasks.

When using cancellation tokens, I would advise the use of [this overload of Task.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194916%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes a `CancellationToken` parameter instead of `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`. The token parameter is used internally by the `Task` to return a cancelled task upon cancellation, failing to use this overload could result in an `OperationCanceledException` being thrown from `Task.Run`.